# read float from a specific line in a file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a series of data files that I need to get a few specific values from.  I know the line in the file that the data is on.  My data files look like this

```
x    y    z
1    0.2  0.3
2    0.1  0.2
3    0.5  0.6
etc.
```

I am using a shell script to access the files, collect the desired data from each file, and output the collected data in one file.

For example, I need the y value in line 3, 0.1.  I have tried the following

```
let dataLine=3
let yVal=`head -n $dataLine dataFile | tail -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'`
```

but I get the following error

```
let: yVal=0.1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".1")
```

I have tried adding `| bc` after `awk '{print $2}'` but then it did not even register the correct value for what should be assigned to `yVal`. When I do it as shown above, it does show that it is recognizing the value in the correct line and column.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, what is the expected output, please add it into post itself and let us know then.

Comment: using `float` values in shell scripting can be a unrewarding challenge. `awk` is designed to handle and all  data types (without requiring type declarations as you'll find in `c` , `java` and many others). You'll find the time spent working thru the tutorial at http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html to be well worth your time. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ dataLine=3
$ yVal=$(awk -v dataLine="$dataLine" 'NR==dataLine{print $2}' data)
$ echo $yVal
0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get 3rd line's 2nd field then following may help you in same.

***Solution 1st:*** If you want to pass any shell variable's value to any `awk` variable then following may help you in same.

```
line_number=3
awk -v line="$line_number" 'FNR==line{print $2}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:*** If you want to directly print 3rd line's 2nd field then following may help you in same.

```
awk 'FNR==3{print $2}'  Input_file
```